# Chrome blocking popup since last update

Tags: jquery, popup, href

Since few days (maybe weeks), chrome is blocking my jQuery function that is opening 2 links when clicking on a button :

JS :

```
jQuery('.link').each(function(){
var th = jQuery(this);
th.on('click', function(){
window.location.href = th.attr('data-main-tab'),
window.open(th.attr('data-new-tab'), th.attr('_blank'));
});
});
```

HTML :

```
<a class="link" data-new-tab="?r=490098534" data-main-tab="https://example.com">Click Here</a>
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Block or allow pop-ups from a specific site:

1. Go to your page where pop-ups are blocked.
2. In the address bar, click Pop-up blocked [image]
3. Click the link for the pop-up you want to see.
4. To always see pop-ups for the site, select Always allow pop-ups and redirects from [your site]
5. Done